# C# DataTable csv IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, indexoutofrangeexception

how can get specific value in 2d index
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;

Row = csvTable.Rows[0](https://easyupload.io/vkv17c).ToString();  got   IndexOutOfRangeException  Cannot find column

```
string fn = $"{oHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\public\\data.csv";
   DataTable csvTable = new DataTable();

        using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(new System.IO.StreamReader(fn), true))
        {
            csvTable.Load(csvReader);

        }
    string headings = csvTable.Columns[0].ToString();


    Row = csvTable.Rows[0][1].ToString(); IndexOutOfRangeException  Cannot find column
```

---

[[the csv for replicate is this][1](https://easyupload.io/vkv17c)](https://easyupload.io/vkv17c)

[example followed](http://using%20LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;)

Comment: I think you are switching around `Columns` and `Rows`.

Comment: i dont want entire row i want  value in 2d specific  index

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** now that you've given the CSV-file I see that you are using `;` (semicolon) as delimiter.

You should let the `CsvReader` know:

```
// Notice the last parameter ';'
using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(new System.IO.StreamReader(fn), true, ';'))
{
    csvTable.Load(csvReader);
}
```

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-read-data-from-csv-file-in-c-sharp/

Comment: @Lollo I see. However I see you are using `;` as delimiter. See my updated answer

Comment: i switched to CsvHelper and got that i want but will try your suggestion